# Merging new data into existing array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this array which I create from some data stored in a database:

```
var chdata = [
  {title: "title one",link: "link one",thumb: "image url one",pcaid: "0001"},
  {title: "title two",link: "link two",thumb: "image url two",pcaid: "0002"},
  {title: "title three",link: "link three",thumb: "image url three",pcaid: "0003"},
  {title: "title four",link: "link four",thumb: "image url four",pcaid: "0004"}
];
```

then I pull back some location data from a geocoding service which arrives in this format:

```
var pcdata = [
  {Distance: "12.2",Latitude: "50.1",Longitude: "0.1",YourID:"0003"},
  {Distance: "80.7",Latitude: "50.4",Longitude: "0.5",YourID:"0001"},
  {Distance: "95.3",Latitude: "50.9",Longitude: "0.7",YourID:"0004"},
  {Distance: "135.1",Latitude: "51.3",Longitude: "0.9",YourID:"0002"},
]
```

The 'pcaid' in chdata and 'YourID' in pcdata are the foreign keys which relate the two arrays if you'll excuse the DBA analogy.

I need to 'each()' through the chdata array, displaying data from it, and the distance of the related item in pcdata. For example in pseudo code:

```
<a href="link one">
  <img src="image url one" /><br />title one (80.7 miles away)
</a>
```

This data needs to be in distance order. My questions are:

1. How do I relate/intersect `chdata` and `pcdata` based on a match between `pcaid` and `YourID`.
2. Once this is done, I plan to use array.sort to get it into Distance order. Do you foresee any problems with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For #1:**  The best setup here would be to have your `pcdata` in a key-value data format.  I'll call that `pchash`.  Then you can use this (relatively) simple syntax:

```
for(var i = 0; i < chdata.length; ++i)
{
    var ch   = chdata[i];
    var dist = pchash[ch.pcaid].distance;
    // Other stuff...
}
```

To transition your current `pcdata` into `pchash`, you can use something like this:

```
pchash = {};
for(var i = 0; i < pcdata.length; ++i)
{
    pchash[pcdata[i]['YourID']] = pcdata[i];
}
```

Or, better yet and if you control the server, have `pcdata` sent over in that format to start with.

**For #2:**  JavaScript arrays have a built-in [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function, and you can pass in a comparator for custom sorting.  In your case, try:

```
whatever.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.Distance - b.Distance;
});
```

If that gives you the reverse of what you want, just subtract `a.Distance` from `b.Distance` instead.

Hope that helps!

**PS:**  Another answer suggests brute-forcing this with a nested loop.  If you have any significant amount of data, I wouldn't recommend it:  It'll take `chdata.length * pcdata.length` iterations, while this will only take `chdata.length + pcdata.length` iterations (or just `chdata.length`, if you get the key-value format from the server).  But on small data sets, the difference won't be noticeable.

Comment: +1 - My answer was based on working with the available data as-is (and I couldn't see any other feasible way of doing it). This approach would be better.

Comment: Xavier, thanks for this. I've used your second snippet to create an object of arrays with the ID as the key. Works well! However It looks like array.sort doesn't work on objects. Do you have a suggestion how I can create an array of arrays that are sortable by modifying your code? Thanks!

Comment: @MereDevelopment - Whoops.  But you're in luck - there's an easy way to work around it.  I've edited the second part; you may need to tweak it a little, but it should be simple now you know the function.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could merge the objects by using [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
$.each(chdata, function(i, x) {
  $.each(pcdata, function(j, y) {
    if(x.pcaid === y.YourID) {

      // at this point you have a match, so you could 
      // either extend the object (like below) 
      $.extend(x, y);

      // just access the properties of each object directly, eg:
      alert(x.title + ' is ' + y.Distance + ' miles away');

    }
  });
});
```

So loop over `chdata`, then loop over `pcdata`, find where the `pcaid` matches `YourID`, then merge the objects (`chdata` will contain the corresponding data from `pcdata`), or access their properties directly.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3n3t/)

Comment: Thanks Billy, I'm attempting to use Xavier's code below as you both think its a better idea, but I might re-visit your's if the object/array comment I left on his cant be answered. Thanks!